# Is there a way to detect screen size in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

Specifically, I would like to make a GET request to a nodejs server, then get the number of monitors and their resolutions for the *server*.

E.g.

```
app.get('/screens', (req, res) => {
    //return the screen info for the computer running this express server
})
```

Comment: Not in NodeJs directly but you could gather this information on the client and put the results in the request you're sending to your NodeJs server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [systeminformation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systeminformation) package.

```
...
const si = require('systeminformation')

app.get('/screens', async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {
      displays
    } = await si.graphics()

    if (!displays.length) {
      throw new Error('No displays')
    }

    res.json({
      displays: displays.length,
      x: displays[0].currentResX,
      y: displays[0].currentResY
    })
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
...
```

`{ displays: 2, x: 1920, y: 1080 }`